# macos, how to remove permissions which cause: "ls: .: Operation not permitted"

Tags: mac-osx

Unfortunately, when onedrive stopped working, I ran the onedrive reset tool. This created a directory under /user/me/ called "OneDrive-Personal (Archive)".

Now onedrive is working again, i have to find a way to diff the whole of my .5 TB onedrive "archive" and the current onedrive dir, to find 3 months worth of work which is in the archive and not saved to onedrive.

Unfortunately, even though its in my home directly, I cant access this with tools like "terminal" and "fileMerge".  I understand I can do bad things like give terminal full disk access, but this doesnt work for fileMerge.

Instead, I want to remove these crazy extra permissions on the OneDrive-Personal (Archive) dir, and just make it a normal permissioned dir which I have access to.

Any idea how I do this?

This is what the permissions look like:

```
lrwxr-xr-x    1 me  staff      51  8 Feb  2022 OneDrive -> /Users/me/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personal
drwx------@  53 me  staff    1696  3 Apr 10:48 OneDrive-Personal (Archive)
```

presumably that "@" indicates the restrictions we need to remove.

maybe I could tar and untar the dir, and disable permission preservation, although I dont think I have enough disk space for this method.

Comment: That `@` indicates Extended Attributes. You can try `ls -l@ ...` to see the Extended Attributes. Alternatively , you can try `xattr -l ...` to get the Extended Attributes. The output on the Containing Directory & the Culprit Directory will show enough information to resolve the Issue.

Comment: Thanks, but ls -l@ nor xattr -l doesnt tell me anything useful, just says "com.apple.macl".  Still dont know how to remove these permissions unfortunately.

Comment: You should include the 4 outputs I listed. That output may have something useful.

Comment: It looks like `xattr -d com.apple.macl ...` will temporarily delete that unwanted attribute , though MacOS will get that restored quickly ! It looks like MacOS wants "the onedrive reset tool" to access that , no other tool should access that !